# Why is my writefile function not working?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

The read file function is working perfectly but the write is not working at all.Please help me to solve this issue. Even I'm not able to find the exact issue.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
filename  byte "Input.txt",0
filelist byte 6000 dup(?),0
filelength dword ?
filehandle dword ?


.code
main PROC
call ReadFileInput
MOV ECX,1000
MOV EDX,offset filelist
CALL WRITESTRING
call WriteFileOutput



;    call dumpregs

    exit
main ENDP

ReadFileInput proc

mov edx,offset filename
call OpenInputFile
mov ecx,10000
mov filehandle, eax
mov edx,offset filelist

call ReadFromFile

mov filelength,eax


RET
ReadFileInput ENDP

WriteFileOutput PROC

mov edx,offset filename
mov eax,filehandle
mov edx,offset filelist
mov ecx, 10000
call WriteToFile
call closefile
Ret
WriteFileOutput ENDP



END main
```

Comment: Please add a tag for your specific CPU architecture. There are many architectures with many assembly languages. I could *guess* it's x86 but *I* shouldn't have to.

Comment: Also, you need to better characterise "not work". Compilation error? Runtime issues? You seem to be calling other procedures not included in this file? Do they provide any error return information, and if so, how are you checking for those errors? (Nothing obvious here for checking errors)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> filelist byte 6000 dup(?),0      <<<<<< 6001 bytes
> filelength dword ?
> filehandle dword ?
>
>
>
> mov ecx,10000                    <<<<<< 10000 bytes
> mov filehandle, eax
> mov edx,offset filelist
> call ReadFromFile
> ```

The *ReadFromFile* operation overwrites the filehandle that you need to later 
*WriteToFile*.

---

Your code misses a call to *CreateOutputFile* before it can actually output something!

The filehandle you got from *OpenInputFile* is not suitable. The mention **...Input...** says it already.

Answer (score 1):

Irvine's [`OpenInputFile`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fopeninputfile.htm) opens the file only for input, i.e. for reading access. But for Irvine's [`WriteToFile`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fwritetofile.htm) you need a handle with writing access. There is no specific function of Irvine's library to open a file with both reading and writing access rights, you have to use the Windows function [`CreateFileA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) which has the prototype [`CreateFile`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Fwin32lib%2Fcreatefile.htm) in Irvine's `SmallWin.inc`

Change

```
mov edx,offset filename
call OpenInputFile
```

to

```
invoke CreateFile, OFFSET filename, GENERIC_READ OR GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0
```